# How to fetch BASE24 messages realtime in my application

Tags: iso8583, jpos, credit-card-track-data

What is the method to fetch BASE24 messages (for Credit/Debt Card transactions etc) of a particular bank network real time through any application which is external to the BASE24 system, if the bank grants me the access so as to analyze these messages.

Answer (score 0):

In the bank test system network you may put your application into the middle of communication channel to play the role transparent switch and collect messages for analyzing. Application should not add the delays to the communication interchange to avoid side effects.

These method can be used to non-secured (plain) socket connections which is not applicable in the real world with external connections.

Before you may need to use TCP/IP listeners like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or tcpdump to collect network packets where you may find Base24 messages and packets details.

Answer (score 0):

BASE24 is a private software owned by ACI Worldwide. You can not access to the software if you don't work in an company related to it. I suggest you to work at the interfaces. They use the ISO8583 protocol message a lot and you can get any information on google, even, make your own implementation.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt someone will grant access to their system, regulations alone are against it

Comment: The answer is irrelevant